# TypeError: $(...).find(...).$ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the HTML value of my `data-` with id so I made this script:

```
$('#body-a').find('[data-id="' + result.rowId + '"]').$("td.qty").html(result.qty);
```

But I get with this error:

> TypeError: $(...).find(...).$ is not a function

I also tried the following script:

```
$('#body-a').find('data-id="' + result.rowId + '"').$("td.qty").html(result.qty);
```

Error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-id="1a06348da52c757b7c3460dae71f464b"

Comment: post code sample of what you have tried so far

Comment: You seem confused.  This is JQuery, and there is no JSON anywhere in this code sample.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe `TypeError: $(...).find(...).$` (meaning the final `$`) is not a function. Hint: the computer will usually tell you exactly what's wrong if you just **read** and **think about** the error messages.

Comment: @torazaburo Depends, chrome has `$` too as their [chrome command line API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference). But it doesn't have `.find` method like jquery does.

Comment: If `$` were the console's shortcut the error message would have complained about the first `.find()` instead.

Comment: Gahhh! Nevermind my comment above!.. I totally thought the error was on the `.find`.. Sorry, my bad.. I need more coffee..

Comment: @torazaburo Yop, you're right. For some reason, I misread the error OP's posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#body-a').find('[data-id="' + result.rowId + '"]').$("td.qty").html(result.qty);
```

The issue here is likley the .$ bit. Have you tried?

```
$('#body-a').find('[data-id="' + result.rowId + '"]').find("td.qty").html(result.qty);
```

You might be able to simplify further

```
$('#body-a [data-id="' + result.rowId + '"] td.qty').html(result.qty);
```

Comment: A template literal would also make the quotes easier. `find(\`[data-id="${result.rowId}"]\`)`